# Vimでテキストファイルを作って書き込もうとしたのですが、「E212: 書込み用にファイルを開けません」と出力されます

Tags: vim

**現象**
Vimでテキストファイル（`/opt/script/clam-full.sh`）を作って書き込もうとしたのですが、「E212: 書込み用にファイルを開けません」と出力されます

**期待値**
`:w`でテキストファイルを作成・書き込みをすることができるようにする

**再現手順**
`$ sudo vim /opt/script/clam-full.sh`を実行し、下記のテキストを入力して書き込み

```
#!/bin/sh
echo =========================================
date
hostname
clamscan / \
     --infected \
     --recursive \
     --log=/var/log/clamav/clamscan.log \
     --move=/var/log/clamav/virus \
     --exclude-dir=^/boot \
     --exclude-dir=^/sys \
     --exclude-dir=^/proc \
     --exclude-dir=^/dev \
     --exclude-dir=^/var/log/clamav/virus

# --infected 感染を検出したファイルのみを結果に出力
# --recursive 指定ディレクトリ以下を再帰的に検査 圧縮ファイルは解凍して検査
# --log=FILE ログファイル
# --move=DIR 感染を検出したファイルの隔離先
# --remove 感染を検出したファイルを削除
# --exclude=FILE 　　検査除外ファイル（パターンで指定）
# --exclude-dir=DIR　検査除外ディレクトリ（パターンで指定）

if [ $? = 0 ]; then
  echo "ウイルス未検出."
else
  echo "ウイルス検出!!"
fi
```

**今まで試した・調べたこと**
`$ ls -l /opt`を実行したところ、`drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096  8月 20 20:49 pigpio`となっていた
root権限がある状態では`rwx`とあるように読み取り・書き込み・実行権限が存在するので、パーミッションの問題ではなさそうです

Comment: `/opt/script/`ディレクトリは存在していますか？無ければ予め作成してからエディタでの作業(保存)を試すとどうなりますか？

Comment: `/opt/script/` ディレクトリが存在していない様に見受けられますが…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

実際の環境でも試してみましたが、コメントにも書いた通り指定したパスに含まれる中間のディレクトリ(`/opt/script/`) が存在しないのが原因だと思われます。

保存先のディレクトリを予め作成してから Vim でファイルを編集・保存してみてください。

```
$ sudo mkdir /opt/script
$ sudo vi /opt/script/clam-full.sh
```

Vim での保存時にエラーが表示されて、「ディレクトリを作成していなかった」事に気づいた場合には、Vim の画面から以下のコマンドで (Vim を抜けずに) コマンドを実行することもできます。

```
:!sudo mkdir /opt/script
```

Answer (score 0):

「書込み用にファイルを開けません」というのですから、clam-full.shというファイルのパーミッションの問題(読み取り専用になっている)だと思います。

・　":w !sudo tee %" というコマンドで強制保存してから、"q!"でvimを終了。
・　clam-full.shのパーミッションを書き込み可能に変更する。
というのを試してみてください。